# Vela kaj uvula prononco de R

Tags: pronunciation

[PMEG diras](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html#i-7fo) ke la prononco de R devas esti trema kaj ke la tremo povas okazi ne nur ĉe la dentoj, sed ankaŭ ĉe uvulo (mi nomos ĝin “franca R” sube).

Mi miras pri tiu permeso, ĉar laŭ miaj oreloj tiu prononco igas la literon R tro simila al aliaj du literoj: H kaj Ĥ. Mi atendus ke PMEG havus rimarkon permesantan la anglan R (kiu sonas sufiĉe malsame kaj ne kaŭzas konfuzon), sed ne atendus ke ĝi akceptas la francan R (kiu malfaciligas la jam malbone konatan Ĥ).

Mi sufiĉe konas la diferencon inter H kaj Ĥ, sed mi ofte pensas ke mi prononcas la francan R kiam mi klopodas prononci Ĥ. Do mi ne kapablus distingi (nek aŭde, nek parole) tiujn tri sonojn se tiu varianto de R estas tiel bona kiel la denta R.

Do, la demando estas: ĉu tiu prononco de R estas sufiĉe klara internacie? Se ne, mi ankaŭ aŭdacus demandi ĉu ĝi vere meritas la mencion en PMEG...

Mi ankaŭ imagas: ĉu povas esti prave, ke la ŝanĝo de -rĥ- al -rk- okazis pro tiu maniero prononci R?

Rimarko: Mi estas brazilano kaj la sono de R en mia lingvo povas varii inter H, Ĥ, kaj pluraj stiloj de R. Do mia konfuzo ne estas surprizo.

Comment: Rilata demando: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/132/is-the-letter-r-supposed-to-be-trilled

Comment: Post iom da tempo, mi trovis ĉi tiun komenton de la Akademio pri Ĥ:
http://akademio.info/akademio/index.php?title=Respondoj_de_la_Lingva_Konsultejo_(parto_11)#Demando_pri_.27k.27_kaj_.27.C4.A5.27 
Tie oni diras ke tia R, kiam ĝi aperas apud Ĥ, fakte povas krei malfacilan sonkombinon [ĥĥ].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mi pensas, ke vi iomete konfuziĝas pri la vera sono, kiun francoj kutime faras por sia *r*: Ĝi kutime ne estas trilo (aliaj realigoj estas dialektaj), sed frikativo ([fonto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Consonants)). Pli precize: La franca *r* kutime estas aŭ *voĉa* aŭ *senvoĉa* *uvulara frikativo* [ʁ], [χ], respektive. La *ĥ* estas la *senvoĉa velara frikativo* [x]. Vi pravas, ke tiuj sonoj estas tre proksimaj, specife [χ] kaj [x] estas malfacile distingeblaj.
Nu, pri la triloj… Laŭ mia sperto la *voĉa uvulara trilo* [ʀ] (via “franca *r*”) kaj la uvularaj frikativoj [ʁ~χ] estas ne tro malfacile distingeblaj (kondiĉe, ke la trilo estas ne tiel mallonga, ke ĝi iĝas frapeto [ʀ̆]). Krome, [ʀ] kaj [ʁ] estas malpli proksimaj unu al la alia, ol [ʀ] kaj [r] (la kutima trilo per la lango: *voĉa alveolara trilo*). T.e., mi mem pli bone povas diferencigi inter [ʀ] kaj [ʁ] ol inter [ʀ] kaj [r]. Do [ʀ] estas sufiĉe proksima al [r], dum [ʁ~χ] ja estas proksima al [x]. Pro tio mi pensas, ke PMEG taksas [ʀ] bona alternativo por [r]. Mi samopinias kun PMEG, sed vi pravas, ke [ʁ] kaj [χ] ne estus bonaj alternativoj por [r], ĉar tiuj sonoj estas tro proksimaj al [x]. La diferenco inter tiuj sonoj kaj [h] (de *h*) estas tute klara laŭ mi, do mi ne vidas tiun problemon.

Pri la angla *r*: *voĉa alveolara alproksimanto* [ɹ]. Mi ne scias, kial PMEG ne permesas tiun sonon. Laŭ mi, ĝi simple ne sonas tiel bele. Sed krome, ĝi ankaŭ estas tre malsama ol [r] kaj [ʀ]. Ĝi simple estas tro malsama por figuri la saman literon. *Sed*, kutime homoj povas fari almenaŭ unu el tiuj tri sonoj: [r], [ʀ] kaj [ɹ]; do se tiuj tri estas permesataj, ne multaj klopodu lerni *r*-sonon por Esperanto. Ankaŭ pro tio mi pensas, ke PMEG permesas [ʀ]: por ke pli da homoj ne devu lerni la malfacilan sonon [r].

Comment: Dankon! Vi donis al mi novan vidpunkton. Mi ne imagis ke oni povus distingi pli facile inter [ʀ] kaj [ʁ] ol inter [ʀ] kaj [r]. Krome, mi do konkludas ke la *vera franca R* ne estas sufiĉe bona por Esperanta R, sed povas esti/fariĝi sufiĉe bona por Esperanta Ĥ (kiel [χ]), ĉu ne? Mi praktikos la distingon inter trilo [ʀ], frikativo [ʁ] kaj “malbona trilo” [ʀ̆]. Se mi povas aldoni demandon, ĉu vi povas facile prononci [ʀx] aŭ [ʀχ]?

Comment: Vi pravas, [χ] certe estas bona alternativo por [x] (*ĥ*). Mi pensas, ke [ʁ] estas iom evitinda, ĉar kelkaj interpretus ĝin kiel *ĥ*, kaj kelkaj kiel *r*! Mi sufiĉe facile povas prononci la sonojn [ʀx] kaj [ʀχ] memstare, kvankam la lasta estas iom pli malfacile ol la unua por mi. Sed, ŝajnas al mi, ke oni facile kunfandas [ʀ] kaj [x~χ] al [ʀ̆x~ʀ̆χ] aŭ eĉ [xː~χː] en kutima parolado.

Answer (score 2):

Post iom da tempo, mi trovis ĉi tiun komenton de la Akademio pri Ĥ:

http://akademio.info/akademio/index.php?title=Respondoj_de_la_Lingva_Konsultejo_(parto_11)#Demando_pri_.27k.27_kaj_.27.C4.A5.27

Tie oni diras ke tia R, kiam ĝi aperas apud Ĥ, fakte povas krei malfacilan sonkombinon [ĥĥ], same kiel mi pensas.

Do mi konkludas ke jes, fakte franceca prononcmaniero povas esti (unu el) la kaŭzo(j) de la ŝanĝo de -rĥ- al -rk-. Tio iomete ankaŭ klarigas kial H ne estis elektita kiel la ĉefa anstataŭo de Ĥ (ĉar -rh- ankaŭ povas fariĝi simile malfacila [ĥh]).

Tamen mi devas aldoni ke, laŭ alia respondo, se oni vere faras bonan trilon (tremadon) por la litero R, eĉ gorĝmaniere ĝi povas fariĝi sufiĉe distingebla de Ĥ kaj H (sed miaopinie la kombino -rĥ- ankoraŭ restus malfacilege prononcebla).

Comment: Ĉu vi kapablas fari ‘velaran trilon’‽

Comment: Laŭ mia propra demando montras, kelkajn detalojn pri prononcmaniero mi ankoraŭ ne bone komprenas. Vi povas legi tiun “aŭ” kiel “iu ajn el tiuj, kiu estas plej ĝusta, mi ne scias”. Aŭ mi povas forigi tiun parentezan noton kaj uzi nur la ne-tiel-sciencan esprimon “gorĝmaniere”. Fakte mi faris tiun redakton.

Comment: Ne zorgu! Estis nur ŝerco, ĉar [oni eltrovis, ke velara trilo estas neebla](http://www.madore.org/~david/misc/linguistic/ipa/) ;).