# How is the Ĥ letter pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, diacritics

The way people explain the pronunciation of the Ĥ letter is rather confusing. The sources I've seen explained it in two very different ways:

1) Like the German CH (like in Sternchen), which is in the aforementioned case a sort of "light" or dampened Ŝ.

2) Like the French R or the Hebrew ר (resh), shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNJtAibUeOc.

Those are very different pronunciations, so, how is the Ĥ letter actually pronounced?

Comment: _Lo**ch** Ness._ might be more known in English.

Comment: Or the yiddish _**ch**utzpah_ (audacity). The Russian **h**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who don't already speak a dozen languages or who have trouble with IPA descriptions, it's easy just to think of of it this way. **Ĥ is a heavy H.**

If you're not sure what that means, there are plenty of good videos on YouTube which include the Esperanto Alphabet. [This video](https://youtu.be/OPsdp1M5pjQ?t=1m5s) seems like as good a one as any to start with.

---

Edit: I received a comment elsewhere that "heavy H" is not helpful, at least to some people. Please be sure to notice the [video link](https://youtu.be/OPsdp1M5pjQ?t=1m5s) in the answer above. By "heavy" I actually mean that there is a restriction in the back of the throat, about where the letter K is pronounced. (I am intentionally avoiding the anatomical terms because most English speakers don't even notice a difference between a palatal k and a velar k.)

Comment: Once again, an answer was downvoted without comment. Please have some courage in your convictions and leave a comment with what is incorrect or could be improved with the answer. As an experienced teacher of Esperanto, I can tell you that this explanation works for most people.

Comment: Sorry. I downvoted it, because the ‘heavy H’ is indeed unhelpful. It's good that you're trying to avoid technical terminology, but ⟨ĥ⟩ is not simply a stronger version of ⟨h⟩. It doesn't answer the question, because with ‘heavy H’ I would not know how to pronounce ⟨ĥ⟩. The video is very helpful though for a pronunciation in context! EDIT: When trying several times making a really forceful ⟨h⟩, I did kind of get to ⟨ĥ⟩ (or more [χ̠ʰ] or something), but that may be because I already can make [x] natively and I just tended towards that.

Comment: If you were to ask me face to face how to pronounce Ĥ and I said "it's a heavy H like this - /Ĥ/ " -- I'm not sure how you could say that didn't answer the question. My answer is basically "it's a heavy H and see this video to understand what I mean." If the video was wrong, then I could see downvoting it.

Comment: Right, but the ‘heavy H’ part doesn't really add anything, as I argued before. Therefore your answer basically becomes ‘like this: <video>’, which is somewhat helpful because it shows the correct sound, but just hearing the sound in a video is not sufficient to know how to make this sound. Hence I stand by my downvote.

Comment: To anybody reading along, that was exactly the point. The question was "is Ĥ pronounced like /ʁ/ in this video" and the answer was "no, like in this video." Clarifications available upon request.

Comment: Fair enough; I've removed the downvote, because the answer to the question is indeed contained in your answer. However, you've formulated your answer as if to answer the question “How does one say ‘ĥ’?”, which was unsatisfactory. It might be helpful to reformulate your answer so that it directly respond to the question.

Comment: I think the "heavy h" explanation that Tomaso gave is excellent,  particularly when paired with helpful videos.  It may not work for everybody,  but it's certainly an explanation that would be helpful and clear to most English- speakers who really do not know how to pronounce Loch Ness in a Scottish manner, or who may not get the comparisons to words / letters in other languages.  And really,  shouldn't we be reserving downvotes for actual misinformation? I think we should. People who go to the trouble of trying to be helpful shouldn't be discouraged from even making an attempt.

Answer (score 10):

I guess you got terrible sources. :/

You just have to check the Fundamento for this:

- In the [English fundamento](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html), ĥ is defined as in loch, which is /x/
- In the [German fundamento](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_germana.html), ĥ is defined as "ch". I think that "ch" in German is mostly /x/ like in [nacht](https://forvo.com/word/sternchen/).[Sternchen](https://forvo.com/word/sternchen/) looks like an oddity.
- In the [French fundamento](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_franca.html), r is defined as the french r, which is /ʁ/, and is how most french speakers do it.

So you have to hear the difference between ĥ (a [**voiceless velar** fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative)) and different r. The "french r" is a [**voiced uvular** fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative). (Which is also the [most common pronunciation for resh in hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resh).) The "german r" is an [**voiced uvular trill**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill#Voiced_uvular_trill). (I added it because it is often miscalled a french r because it is guttural.)

Comment: The problem is that there are regional accents. What we're told in Switzerland is that the pronunciation of Sternchen and Ich are the same, that is, as i described. Sternchen is no exception. And also that Nacht is pronounced with a sort of french R sound. The other problem is that the HX sound is difficult to find well recorded, so that you don't hear much when you hear it... If you have a clear recording of the sound in context, please let me know!.

Comment: This answer does a good job of explaining why there are confusing explanations. It seems to stop short, however, of actually answering the question. The question, as I read it, was "which explanation is correct?" The answer is /x/. (If most French speakers pronounce Ĥ as /ʁ/, then most French speakers speak with a French pronunciation and not an international one.) For sure the "resh" video does not demonstrate a good Ĥ sound.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander If the question is "which explanation is correct", I think I did a good explanation: none of them. I think you read my answer too quickly and confused r with ĥ. The explanation 2 is incorrect because it shows a way to do r (the french way), not how to do ĥ.

Comment: @Vanege - Please pardon me if I'm reading it wrong, but I don't see where you answer whether the correct way is /x/ or /ʁ/.

Comment: Sternchen is not an oddity: German has two allophones of ch, the so-called Ich-Laut /ç/ following the vowels e, i, ä, ö, ü and consonants, also used at the beginning of a word (or word segment), and the so-called Ach-Laut /x/ following the vowels a, o, and u. Esperanto ĥ is always Ach-Laut, not matter of its environment.

Comment: I'm seriously wondering why no one mentioned Ach-Laut earlier, for one with some German it should be all that needs to be said.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments so far a few wrong things with regard to German were said, I think a new answer has some merit, especially for German speaking learners of Esperanto.

To say 'ĥ' is pronounced like 'ch' in German is not very helpful and wrong in two of three cases. Actually, German has three allophones for its /x/ phoneme. These are [χ] as in *ach*, [x] as in *Tuch* and [ç] as in *ich*. Neither is 'ĥ' pronounced like 'ch' in *ach* nor like in *Sternchen*.

So [ĥ equals [x]](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html#i-n4b), a velar voiceless fricative. For speakers of German: It is pronounced like 'ch' in *Tuch*.

Comment: I think [χ] is an acceptable variation of Ĥ. Almenaŭ Joffysloffy konsentas tie ĉi: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/986/vela-kaj-uvula-prononco-de-r